# What program can be used to package software into one executable?

Tags: portable

I need to package an application into a single executable file (so that I don't have to install it, so that it will be portable).  Does anybody know what I can use to make a program portable?

Comment: Since we closed the other question, we should probably leave this one open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [VMware Thin App](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/overview.html):

> With VMware ThinApp, applications are packaged into single executables that run completely isolated from each other and the operating system for conflict-free execution on end-point devices.

I'm not sure if this approach is useful for a software like Hotspot Shield though.

Answer (score 4):

[VMWare ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/overview.html) is the best option that I know, but you can make portable apps using WinRAR (or 7-zip, but I don't know how).

> Tutorial on [how to make a portable application with VMWare ThinApp.](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1500-make-a-portable-application-with-thinapp)

Answer (score 1):

Originally there was PEBundle (discontinued). Thinstall became VMWare ThinApp. Now there is MoleBox as far as shareware/cheap solutions.