# Windows - how to install one program but have the ability to swap its settings/licenses (container?)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, licensing, container

This is an odd one to explain, bear with me.

We have a program, call it Program-A.  We run this program on our Windows machines on behalf of customers, but each customer has their own license for it.  The first time we install it we use Customer-A's license, but instead of un-installing and installing again for Customer-B with their license, it would be good if we could just somehow swap the application settings/licensing/registry etc, especially as we may need to swap between customers many times a day.

I know how the program stores settings/licenses is going to be specific, which is why I'm wondering if there is a generic way of 'containing' an application during an install, like a virtual environment.

To take it one step further, it would be ideal if this 'container' could be stored and copied to any Windows machine - so instead of installing it, we just "run" it and it thinks its already installed.

Update 1: the application we use is run from the command line, so we need to be able to start it by absolute path to the executable.

Update 2: preferably it needs to be open-source/freeware as we don't have a budget for anything right now :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [What program can be used to package software into one executable?](http://superuser.com/questions/275202/what-program-can-be-used-to-package-software-into-one-executable), [Creating portable version of program by wrapping all essential files](http://superuser.com/questions/702200/creating-portable-version-of-program-by-wrapping-all-essential-files)

Comment: Your budget does not matter, and asking straight up for software to do "Y" (instead of asking for a way to solve problem "X") is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

A virtual machine for each customer would work.  However, depending on how many customers, it may use more hard drive than you have.

You could store them on a read-only network share and copy and paste them on the local PC on an as needed basis.

There is a chance the settings could be stored in a self contained folder in the registry you could export and then import a different registry file for each customer.  This uses way less disk space, but gathering up the necessary registry entries and combining them into a single file is going to take a lot of time.